# Custom 'with open()' statement in Python: generator didn't yield error

Tags: python, with-statement

I have a class for a file, from which you can parse data, write data etc. I want to use it from any application like this:

```
f = MyFileClass() # __init__ method puts a lot of default data in object
with f.open() as file: # where f.open() is custom MyFileClass method
    file.write("foo") # file should close automatically after this
```

I tried this:

```
# it's in MyFileClass()
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def open(self):
    try:
        return open(os.path.join(self.directory, self.name), self.flags)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.__traceback__)
```

but I got after running first code

`line 22, in fill_new_file
    with f.open() as file:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\contextlib.py", line 61, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None
RuntimeError: generator didn't yield`

I guess it's not how contextmanagers works. How to do what I want?

Comment: I'd wouldn't call that custom context manager `open` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Was going to comment but things turn out to be too complicated to leave there, but I do have an answer.

The corrected version of code can be reduced to essentially this

```
@contextmanager
def myopen(path):
    try:
        yield open(path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.__traceback__)
```

Before we try, let's get a count of open file handles using this:

```
>>> os.listdir('/proc/self/fd')
['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

Now use our context manager

```
>>> with myopen('/tmp/a_file') as f:
...     print(f.read())
...     print(os.listdir('/proc/self/fd'))
... 
Contents of file

['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Yup, file descriptor count increased, but now that we are out of our context manager, let's see

```
>>> print(os.listdir('/proc/self/fd'))
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Uh that defeats the purpose of having a context manager for the file (we want to use the default autoclosing function, so restart the interpreter, and try this.

```
@contextmanager
def myopen(path):
    try:
        with open(path) as f:
            yield f
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.__traceback__)
```

Rerun our tests

```
>>> with myopen('/tmp/a_file') as f:
...     print(f.read())
...     print(os.listdir('/proc/self/fd'))
... 
Contents of file

['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Now outside the context manager

```
>>> print(os.listdir('/proc/self/fd'))
['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

Yay, looks like it worked (file is successfully closed), but what about a path that does not exist to see that exception handling?

```
>>> with myopen('/tmp/no_path') as f:
...     print(f.read())
... 
<traceback object at 0x7f6b64b618c8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 61, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None
RuntimeError: generator didn't yield
```

The exception block did fire, note that `traceback` object, but then since the context manager did not correctly yield, a different exception is raised like what you saw before.  I don't know what to recommend, but what I recommend is log the error (using a logger) and then reraise the exception.  You could consider returning a dummy object of some kind that will then raise the exception when read, or return nothing, but you need to decide on what exactly is best for your case.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
@contextmanager
def open(self):
    try:
        yield open(os.path.join(self.directory, self.name), self.flags)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.__traceback__)
```

Context managers are generators, not functions.

Comment: Should really do something like `with open(...) as f:` then `yield f` so that the file gets closed as intended, otherwise the file will get opened multiple times if the `MyFileClass.open` gets called multiple times.

Comment: I agree: One should use class-based context manager where you close the file in `__exit__` https://docs.python.org/dev/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I want to use file like I mentioned in my first code (what I mean by that is simple usage), eg. `with f.open_file() as f:`). How should I write this then? Use `with` statement in my contexmanager, as @metatoaster wrote?