# How to write a context manager with contextlib.contextmanager where I only log on failure

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield, contextmanager

I'm trying to write a context manager with `contextlib.contextmanager`.  The following works as expected:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def Dir(path):
    path = Path(path).expanduser().resolve()
    try:
        path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        yield path
    except PermissionError as err:
        print(err)
        raise err
```

However if I want it to log and suppress the exception by removing the `raise err` line, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/python3.7/contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
    112             return next(self.gen)
    113         except StopIteration:
--> 114             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None
    115 
    116     def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):

RuntimeError: generator didn't yield
```

What am I missing?

PS: I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445177) old question, but it does not resolve my issue.

Comment: When you write `with Dir("foo") as path:`, and there is an error, what would `path` be? There is no way for a `contextmanager` to not run its function, except by throwing an exception. If you suppress the exception, you have to `yield`.

Comment: When there's an error, the code block shouldn't run.  `yield`ing again leads to an `None` being passed on to the code block, which is worse!  When there's an error, I just want to log instead of raising an exception.  I'll add an example in my question to show what I am expecting.

Comment: I know what you're expecting. But I will repeat myself: There is no way for a `contextmanager` to not run its function, except by throwing an exception. What you want is, AFAIK, not possible in Python. `if` is there for conditional execution; `try` is there to handle exceptional cases; `with` is there to execute something with a resource. You can't abuse `with` as a conditional, or error recovery.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090497/240443) for the closest alternative.

Comment: @Amadan Okay, I see what you mean.  I'll reconsider my approach.  And thanks for the link